# Compile error for a simple library in Android using latest FFmpeg library with NDK

Tags: android, ubuntu, ffmpeg, android-ndk, 64-bit

I'm trying to get FFmpeg working in Android , and after successfuly compiled it on **Ubuntu 64bit** , and created the Android.mk under source/ffmpeg-3.4.2/android/arm folder and also the Android.mk in my own Android project 
! i'm unable to compile  a simple program  and create the .so file !
By the way i've searched over the net and in Stackoverflow for 2 days now without luck !
here is the code **Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := MyLibrary
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := MyNativeFunctions.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lz -llog
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libavformat_static libavcodec_static libavutil_static
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,ffmpeg-3.2.4/android/arm)
```

The native functions

```
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
    #include <libavutil/avutil.h>

    #include <android/log.h>
    #define LOG_TAG "mylib"
    #define LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
    #define LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
    jint Java_com_example_home_hellondk_MyNativeFunctions_TestNdk(JNIEnv * env, jobject this, jstring filename)
    {
         av_register_all();

return 0;
}
```

when i use NDK-BUILD here is the error i got :

```
/home/home/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/ffmpeg-3.2.4/android/arm/lib/libavformat.a: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/libMyLibrary.so] Error 1
```

[EDIT]
**Build_android.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=/home/home/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-24/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
 function build_one
{
./configure \
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--disable-shared \
--enable-static \
--disable-doc \
--disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-ffserver \
--disable-avdevice \
--disable-doc \
--disable-symver \
--cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--target-os=linux \
--arch=arm \
--enable-cross-compile \
--sysroot=$SYSROOT \
--extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
--extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
$ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make
make install
}
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
build_one
```

**[EDIT]**
The problem has been solved by adding the missing library in 
**LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libavformat_static libavcodec_static libswscale_static libavutil_static libswresample_static**
and for all users of Android Studio do not forget to add this line to your gradle otherwise it won't work.

```
sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
    }
```

**Best regards**

Comment: How did you build libavformat?

Comment: @DanAlbert: Please check the update "Build_android.sh"

Comment: If i remove av_register_all() it works fine ! i can't understand where is the problem !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only building ffmpeg for arm32 but you're building your app for all ABIs.

Here in your ffmpeg build script you're targeting arm specifically:

```
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-24/arch-arm/
```

And from the error output you can see it was building arm64:

```
make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/libMyLibrary.so] Error 1
```

Either limit your ndk-build to building only arm32 (`APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a` in your `Application.mk`) or build ffmpeg for the other architectures as well.

By the way, you'll have an easier time building autoconf projects with the NDK if you use https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your support ! i really appreciate it ! you are right , but now i'm getting a new errors : libavformat/hls.c:762: error: undefined reference to 'atof'
libavformat/hlsenc.c:454: error: undefined reference to 'atof'
libavformat/webmdashenc.c:85: error: undefined reference to 'atof'
l..................
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libMyLibrary.so] Error 1

Comment: I've added : APP_PLATFORM := android-24 and now i get some other  errors  libavcodec/opusdec.c:379: error: undefined reference to 'swr_is_initialized' what does this mean !?

Comment: Opus depends on **libswresample**. Add this library to list of  LOCAL_EXPORTED_STATIC_LIBRARIES in source/ffmpeg-3.4.2/android/arm/Android.mk or specify `--disable-decoder-opus` when you configure **ffmpeg**.

Comment: Thank you @Dan for your help the problem has been solved , i've added the libswresample_static libswscale_static and it compile fine now . Thank you so much for the hint of APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a it was very helpful